# Is it possible to go into an array and take only some values of that array and make a new array?

Tags: java, arrays

For example, lets say that I have an array

```
String[] array = {"hello", "bye", "yo", "ufc", "nba", "kobe"};
```

Is it possible to use a for loop to go into the array and make a new array with every 3 words so they new arrays would be:

```
String[] newArray = {"hello", "bye", "yo"}
String[] newArray2 = {"ufc", "nba", "kobe"}
```

This is java btw. Thank you.

Comment: Sure it is. What have you tried?

Comment: It is, though in my opinion an array object would be a better fit for this task

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] newArray = new String[3];
for (int i = 0 ; i < nRecords ; i++) {
   newArray[i] = array[i + startRecord];
}
```

You should decide how to store all the arays. You can't generate variables with new name. You could use 2D array String[][] arrays;

full sample:

```
    int nRecords = 3;
    String[] array = {"hello", "bye", "yo", "ufc", "nba", "kobe"};
    int nArrays = array.length / nRecords;
    String[][] newArrays = new String[nArrays][];
    for (int k = 0; k < nArrays; k ++)  { 
      newArrays[k] = new String[nRecords];
      for (int i = 0 ; i < nRecords ; i++) {
        newArrays[k][i] = array[i + k * nRecords];
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete working example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] array = {"hello", "bye", "yo", "ufc", "nba", "kobe"};

    List<String[]> every3 = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; )
    {
        int len = (i < array.length - 3) ? 3 : array.length - i;
        String [] newArr = new String [len];
        
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
        {
            newArr[j] = array[i++];
        }
        every3.add(newArr);
    }
    
    for (String [] arr : every3)
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

**Outputs**:

> [hello, bye, yo]
>
> [ufc, nba, kobe]

**Note**: This code also works if the length of the main array is not a multiple of 3;

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Use Arrays.copyOfRange](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

**Code**

```
String[] newArray  = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, 3);
String[] newArray2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 3, array.length);
```

**result**

```
//newArray
hello bye yo 

//newArray2
ufc nba kobe
```